# Anaconda Mode only complete module variables, get No Matches for assigned variables on linux server accessed via ssh

Tags: spacemacs, python, anaconda-mode

Description

Anaconda Mode only complete module variables, get No Matches for
assigned variables on linux server accessed via ssh

Reproduction guide

*Observed behaviour:*
- Start Emacs

- execute `import pandas as pd`
- type `pd.` tab, it shows list of candidates
- execute `df = pd.DataFrame()`
- type `df.` tab, it says No Matches

*Expected behaviour:*
Show completion for `df.` tab

anaconda mode buffer shows no error. I also tried `pip install
--upgrade jedi json-rpc service_factory`. I am more than happy to
provide more info.

System Info

- OS: gnu/linux
- Emacs: 25.3.1
- Spacemacs: 0.200.13
- Spacemacs branch: master (rev. c7a103a77)
- Graphic display: nil
- Distribution: spacemacs
- Editing style: vim
- Completion: helm
- Layers:
  `elisp
  (helm auto-completion better-defaults emacs-lisp git markdown org sdefaults sdired sorg c-c++ python html yaml sql csv docker
    (latex :variables latex-enable-auto-fill t latex-enable-folding t)
    semantic spell-checking syntax-checking)`
- System configuration features: XPM JPEG TIFF GIF PNG SOUND NOTIFY LIBXML2 FREETYPE XFT ZLIB TOOLKIT_SCROLL_BARS LUCID X11

Comment: It's Ipython version issue. 7.2.0 does not work but 6.2.1 works.