# python-shell-completion-complete-or-indent no mathes in ipython

Tags: spacemacs, python

```
import pandas as pd
pd. # press tab, there are completions
df = pd.DataFrame()
df. # press tab, No Matches
```

Same configuration worked on my local mac but not on linux server.

If I use python interpreter instead of Ipython, it also works.

Ipython completion worked in terminal. It does not work in Emacs.

I am happy to provide more details but I even don't know where to look for bugs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anaconda Mode only complete module variables, get No Matches for assigned variables on linux server accessed via ssh](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46597/anaconda-mode-only-complete-module-variables-get-no-matches-for-assigned-variab)

Answer (score 0):

It's Ipython version issue. 7.2.0 does not work but 6.2.1 works.

Comment: Can you add more information to your question such as a suggestion to downgrade ipython?

Comment: Try https://github.com/ipython/rlipython

Comment: Seems to be fixed as of IPython 7.3, see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11541